# JQGrid plugin show duplicated rows and buttons when it is included from another view

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am using:

```
compile ":jquery-ui:1.8.24"
compile ":jqgrid:3.8.0.1"
```

If I open my JQGrid controller, it shows the table perfectly.

But if I include this controller from another controller view:

```
<g:include controller="comentario" action="JQGrid" />
```

It shows duplicated rows and buttons:

[image: printscreen of duplicated rows and buttons]

**I discovered that this problem disappear if I delete the next line from layouts/main.gsp:**

```
<g:layoutHead/>
```

But I'd like to know what's happening around. I don't think the above solution is the best solution.

Comment: This is an expected behavior if you try to add [Layouts in Layouts](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2011/04/grails-goodness-applying-layouts-in.html). Also have a look at [Layouts in Layouts Revisited](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2011/04/grails-goodness-applying-layouts-in.html) for more insight on how layouts work in Grails.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @dmahapatro, but I don't understand what should I do, or why the layout fails. Should I add  `<g:layout*/>` and `<g:pageProperty/>` somewhere?